# c# как взять переменную из другого класса

Tags: c#

из класса tovar нужно взять переменную selectColvoTav в класс zapic.Подскажите как правильно это сделать

```
   class tovar
    {
        
        public static void GetColvo()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("товар " + i + "  кол-во товара (10)" + "| чтобы выбрать нажмите(" + i + ")");
            }

            int tovar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите кол-во товара");
            int selectColvoTav = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (selectColvoTav > 10)
            {

                while (selectColvoTav > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка!!! у нехватает товара");
                    Console.WriteLine("Выберите кол-во товара");
                    selectColvoTav = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if(selectColvoTav <= 10)
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class zapic
    {
        public static void Zapic()
        {
            string writePath = @"D:\hta.txt";

 

            string text = "товар 1  " + "кол-во товара - " + Convert.ToString(tovar.selectColvoTav);
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.WriteLine("Запись выполнена");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это всё ужасно, конечно. Но если уж делать в стиле Вашего кода, то:

```
public class tovar
{
    public int selectColvoTav {get; set;}
    public static void GetColvo()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("товар " + i + "  кол-во товара (10)" + "| чтобы выбрать нажмите(" + i + ")");
        }

        int tovar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите кол-во товара");
        selectColvoTav = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (selectColvoTav > 10)
        {

            while (selectColvoTav > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка!!! у нехватает товара");
                Console.WriteLine("Выберите кол-во товара");
                selectColvoTav = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if(selectColvoTav <= 10)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я так же сделал только без get и set ,это что такое

Comment: а как бы вы реализовали эту задачу если не лень можете рассказать

Comment: @govnocoder а чем вам get set мешает?

Comment: Да тут много проблем, очевидные: лишние зависимости (в коде класса товар не должно быть ссылки на консольные методы), перегрузка ответственности классов, обработка ошибок, ну и самое простое наименования классов. Я бы сделал класс товар со свойствами наименование товара и количество и создавал объекты товаров уже в точке опроса пользователя. Отдельно бы сделал метод дисплей для каждого товара.